# jquery ui dialog validation, methods for isdigit, istext and date range helpers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to valid form fields in a jquery dialog.

Are there any helper functions for checking:

1. if entered only digits
2. if only text
3. date range is within a specified range
4. is not empty
5. is drop down selected

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking for client side validation I did quite a bit of research and chose the [JQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin and have had good success.
It's fairly easy to implement and very customisable.

Demo's can be found [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)